# Lotus Notes mail forwarding with a REST URL

Tags: objective-c, rest, lotus-domino, lotus

I want to forward Lotus Notes mail using a REST API with Objective C. With this method, the mail is still in the Draft directory, but never sent.

```
https://servername/mail/xxx.nsf/($Drafts)/$new/?EditDocument&Form=l_JSVars&PresetFields=Form=m_SentView,s_NotesForm;memo,s_CopyFromUnid;parentUnid
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That URL is not part of the Domino REST API. It's part of the old URL command set for rendering Domino data into HTML for accessing Domino applications in a browser.

Comment: Thanks Richard ! I'm not sure that it was an old command. We can find them in version 9 of Lotus: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_DOMINO_URL_COMMANDS_4332.html. Did you have an idea for the forward mail URL command ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is not a URL command to forward or send an email. I believe that the way to do this would be by using the [Domino Data Service's Document PUT](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html#ddapi_ref_document_put) command to create a new document in the server's mail.box database.  If your goal is to forward, your code will have to read the existing document, add the required item values for mailing (e.g., SendTo, etc.) and PUT the result into mail.box.

Comment: Thanks again Richard. I'll try following your recommandation.

Comment: Hi Richard,I'm able to create well new document with the URL :@"servername/mail/databse/($Drafts)/$new/?EditDocument&Form=... but the new document is still in the Draft folder and don't send to the user. Did you have an idea of the parameter to add to send it ? I have try a lot off without success... Thanks

Comment: Don't create the message in the Drafts folder of the user's mail file. You want to create it in the server's mail.box database instead (that would be "servername/mail.box"). The problem is that the command you are using relies on the Form, which is in the user's mailbox but not in the server's mail.box, so this technique won't work.

Comment: Continuing... That's why you really should stop trying to use the old URL commands. They are not intended for what you are doing. And also, since they are not supported as a general-purpose API they are potentially subject to changing behavior with different versions of Domino, so if you find a solution it might break after an upgrade. Switch to using the Domino Data Service instead. It does not depend on the existence of a form, or agents, or anything else that is specific to the user's mail file. It just works directly with documents and items. And it is a supported general-purpose API.

Comment: Thanks again Richard, for this pertinente recommandation. Didi you have an example or a reference link for sending a email with this technique ?

Comment: The reference for DDS is already linked in my answer. I do not have an example for DDS, but here is a link to some code that uses a very similar technique in a LotusScript class. Instead of using the NotesDocument.Send method, it directly creates documents in the server's mail.box file in order to have more control over the process. Look at the code after Public Sub Send() in this class to see which items you will need to set in your call to the DDS Document PUT method. http://blog.texasswede.com/lotusscript-mail-notification-class/